# Line breaks not working in php string

Tags: php

I have the following function which I'm for enqueuing styles in PHP pretty similar to the WordPress function.

```
public function printHTML() {
        foreach($this->styles as $style) {
            $style = sprintf('<link href="%s" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n', $style);
            $this->print_html .= $style;
        }
        return $this->print_html;
}
```

And when calling this inside my **index.php** page, I do the following :

```
echo nl2br($styles->printHTML());
```

But it appears to just throw the whole **print_html** into 1 line which looks ugly within the source, any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` only works in a double quoted string i.e. echo `"\n";` or in your case

```
$style = sprintf("<link href='%s' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />\n", $style);
```

Or done more simply

```
$this->print_html .= "<link href='$style' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />\n";
```